# Show polygon from database using yii2-google-map-library

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, yii2-advanced-app

i have problem when i'm trying to show polygon from database using `yii2-google-maps-library`. i've table `tb_wilayah` with field `(id, label, lat, lng)` and then i try to show the polygon on map with this code :

```
$data = AreaWilayah::find()->all();
    $paths = [];
    foreach ($data as $value){
        $koord = new LatLng([
            'lat' => $value->lat,
            'lng' => $value->lng
        ]);
        array_push($paths, $koord);
    }
    $coords = [$paths];
    $polygon = new Polygon([
        'paths' => $coords
    ]);
    $map->addOverlay($polygon);
```

unfortunatelly i've error message `Argument 1 passed to dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\PolygonOptions::addCoord() must be an instance of dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\2amigos\yii2-google-maps-library\overlays\PolygonOptions.php on line 120 and defined`
could someone help me? or if someone could provide a tutorial, that would be a real help.

Comment: The error is clear, you are passing array instead of object instance. Check accurately your code again and replace array with `LatLng` object.

Comment: @Arta09 did you figure out solution? I am having the same exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the above code. That pointed me in the right direction. This worked for me:

```
foreach ($ismalls as $mall) {
    $poly_json = json_decode($mall->polygonpoints, true);
    $coords = [];
    //echo print_r($poly_json);
    foreach ($poly_json as $points) {
        $koord = new LatLng([
            'lat' => $points[1],
            'lng' => $points[0]
        ]);
        array_push($coords, $koord);
    }
   $polygon = new Polygon([
        'paths' => $coords
    ]);

    // Add a shared info window
    $polygon->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow([
        'content' => '<p>'.$mall->display_name.'</p>'
        ]));

    // Add it now to the map
    $map->addOverlay($polygon);
}
```